# How to setup Eclipse development for a maven project using provided scope to all dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, keycloak

I am trying to setup my Eclipse to begin development but the example projects I am working on have all its dependencies as provided. So Eclipse could not resolve all the classes it needs and I don't know how to resolve the dependencies.

I am not sure if I should change the scope from provided to compile or just none.

The example I am trying to work on is Keycloak's auth provided example.

Comment: Do you have set the project within the eclipse as maven project? If not eclipse does not get the dependencies from the maven pom.xml.

Comment: I used Import from Existing Maven Projects. I am going to try something else. The project is looking for a version that currently does not exist in the Maven Central Repository.

Comment: I see that would explain the problem - maybe a local nexus was used that has the missing artifacts. If such artifacts are found in other repositories you could add such repositories to the pom. If not you could manipulate them into your local maven repo - mostly at c:\User\YouUsername\.m2\repository\ at the right position - adding the jar and create a pom for it. But maybe that is to much for you at the moment.
Also do you have tried running maven clean install from the commandline?

Comment: Sigh... I changed <version>4.6.0.Final-SNAPSHOT</version> to <version>4.5.0.Final</version> and everything worked. I really thought that I was doing something wrong and questioned my ability to be an engineer. Anyway, maybe I need to set a repository tag but it's not included in the actual git of the project.